# Should I make a custom bootloader?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

I'm on a project where I'll use a BLE chip and I saw I can craft a custom bootloader.
I don't think I'll need to make a custom one because it's just going to be a bridge to other chips (but aren't all bluetooth systems like this?)

Q: **How do I know that I should create a bootloader?**

Bonus question: **Do you have tips about creating one?**

Edit: I'm using a EFR32BG22 with simplicity studio 5

Comment: It would probably help if you specific the chip/platform you are going to use.